# Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) Objective C

Tags: objective-c, voip

I was looking into Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) and thought to try it myself.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

I have already gone through the below link:

[iOS: Open Source VoIP/SIP Objective-C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/ios-open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code)

I need to try sample or demo application with code so that can understand the concept behind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Linphone and Siphone with pjsip. Linphone works great out of the box, siphone need a litle tweaking.

Comment: Thanks @Radu for answering. I am trying Linphone. :)